# best minimilist control panel for linux server

Tags: linux, web-server, vps

I have a linux VPS, we have some sites hosted on it, and we need an opensource Control panel with basic features such as domain addition, email address addition and stuff. Can someone give me some names ?

Answer (score 3):

[Webmin](http://webmin.com) is pretty lightweight from what I can remember, but it's been several years since I touched it. In webmin, you can enable/disable "modules" at need to tune functionality to suit your needs.

Comment: i found it rather heavy for something this small

Comment: Fair enough. "Lightweight" is somewhat subjective, so to each his own.

Answer (score 1):

better use virtualmin, the webmin hosting module:

http://www.webmin.com/virtualmin.html

http://www.webmin.com/vinstall.html

Answer (score 0):

Give [ISPCP Omega](http://isp-control.net/) a try. It is my preference, However may not be the most "light-weight", as being lightweight trades off with functionality. You can also might want to have a look at the "Comparison of web hosting control panels" on Wikipedia (Sorry was not allowed to hyper-link the later!)